# Need a dynamic PHP gallery

Tags: php, html, mysql, gallery

So, I've made a login page where the user gets redirected to a folder on the server that corresponds to the registered username if the login info is correct.

Now I need a way to dynamically (or I need another admin page to deal with adding new content) page that will list all the images and or videos that are available to this user.

This should be presented as thumbnails like in a gallery. Each of these thumbnails will represent a "project", and if the user clicks any of these he will get to a page where he can see all the content (multiple images/videos, some details, and the ability to download the images he wants).

Also, I want to be able to sort the main content. So I can tag each project with multiple tags, and later sort them to show me only related projects.

Now, how do I do this? :P

I'm not too good at php, but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction?
I would also guess a sql database would be good here, but the simpler the better. :)

I basically dont know where to begin this, and I've spend some time looking through the web to see if there already exists some scripts I can use to do this. But so far I'm still left with only the working login page :P

---

In case I'm not clear, this is what I want:

The user is presented with the projects available to him. He can click any of then to get all the images and or videos in that particular project. He can then also download the images he wants in full resolution from the server.
[image]

Comment: I would be tempted to look at 'off-the-shelf' solutions. There are several free ones, and some of them are extremely customizable.

Comment: I wouldnt mind that. Do you know of any you can recommend?

Comment: Well, for one of my sites, I use a product called Gallery3. I only use it for 'back-end' stuff but I guess it's fine for 'front-end' too - although I haven't used it with movie files.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) to read the contents from the directory.

But I would much rather suggest storing it in a a database with the relevant tags, images and content so that it becomes easier to manage.

In that case you can use normal AJAX calls to retrieve stuff from the DB to help you with upload/download.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks mate. Yes, everything helps :) I'm looking at another similar site we have here, and I'm trying to understand how to do this.. =)

Comment: Cool let me know if you get stuck @StianBergLarsen somewhere :) or have any questions .. maybe I can add to the answer.